# How to set cronjob on wake up from sleep?

Tags: linux, cron, power-management, crontrigger

For example if you want a cron job to run after each reboot, you add sth like this to your cron file:

```
@reboot ./do_sth
```

Is there something similar to that for waking up from a *sleep* state?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not something that can be managed by cron, but it can be managed by the Power Management Utilities (`pm-utils`). When reading `man pm-action`, you find:

> **`/etc/pm/sleep.d, /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`:**
> Programs in these directories (called hooks) are combined and executed in C sort order before suspend and hibernate with as argument `suspend` or `hibernate`. Afterwards, they are called in reverse order with argument `resume` and `thaw` respectively. If both directories contain a similar named file, the one in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` will get preference. It is possible to disable a hook in
> the distribution directory by putting a non-executable file in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, or by adding it to the `HOOK_BLACKLIST` configuration variable.

So all you need to do is create a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` that looks like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
action="$1"

case "$action" in
   suspend)
        # List programs to run before, the system suspends
        # to ram; some folks call this "sleep"
   ;;
   resume)
        # List of programs to when the systems "resumes"
        # after being suspended
   ;;
   hibernate)
        # List of programs to run before the system hibernates
        # to disk; includes power-off, looks like shutdown
   ;;
   thaw)
        # List of programs to run when the system wakes
        # up from hibernation
   ;;
esac
```

Obviously, you can alter this if you do not want to distinguish between `suspend` and `hibernate`, or `resume` and `thaw` into something like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
action="$1"
case "$action" in
   suspend|hibernate) stuff ;;
   resume|thaw)       stuff ;;
esac
```