# How to create a cron job in server for starting celery app?

Tags: cron

the server where I have hosted my app usually restarts due to maintenance and when it does a function that I kept open in the background stops and I have to manually turn it on.

Here are the commands that I do in ssh

```
ssh -p19199 -i <my ssh key file name> <my username>@server.net

source /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/activate

cd /home/myapp/app

celery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log --detach
```

I need to start this celery app whenever there is no 'celery' function in the command `ps axuww`. If it is running already then it will show:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
myapp  8792  0.1  0.2 1435172 82252 ?       Sl   Jun27   1:27 /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/python3 -m celery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log
myapp  8898  0.0  0.2 1115340 92420 ?       S    Jun27   0:32 /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/python3 -m celery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log
myapp  8899  0.0  0.2 1098900 76028 ?       S    Jun27   0:00 /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/python3 -m celery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log
myapp  8900  0.0  0.2 1098904 76028 ?       S    Jun27   0:00 /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/python3 -m celery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log
myapp  8901  0.0  0.2 1098908 76040 ?       S    Jun27   0:00 /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/python3 -m celery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log
myapp 28216  0.0  0.0  10060  2928 pts/1    Ss   15:57   0:00 -bash
myapp 28345  0.0  0.0  49964  3444 pts/1    R+   15:57   0:00 ps axuww
```

I need the cron job to check every 15 minutes.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58405459/8344060) question and answer.

Comment: you should define a systemd service this link could help https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/systemd.service.5.html

Answer (score 2):

You have everything figured out already, just put it inside a *IF* block in a shell (Bash) script, save it wherever you feel like (eg, `$HOME`). After the script, we'll set Cron.

I'm gonna call this script "`start_celery.sh`":

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -ue
#
# Start celery only if it is not running yet
#
if [[ `ps auxww | grep "[c]elery"` ]]; then

  source /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/activate
  cd /home/myapp/app
  celery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log --detach

fi
```

> **Remember** to make it executable!

```bash
$ chmod +x start_celery.sh
```

A few notes:

- the output from `ps` is being filtered by `grep "[c]elery"` because we don't one the *grep* line that would come out if we simply did `grep "celery"` (reference: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grep-exclude-ps-results).

  > Using `grep "celery" | grep -v "grep"` would not work in our case because we want to use the *lack* of *celery* commands (exit code "1") to trigger the *IF* block.
- setting "`-ue`" in the script fails the whole thing/script in case something goes wrong (this is a precaution I always use, and I live it here as a shared knowledge/hint. Even if we are not using variables (`-u`) I like to use it). Feel free to remove it. (reference https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Now we have the script -- `~/start_celery.sh` in our home directory, we just have to include it in our (user's) crontab jobs. To do that, we can use some help from some websites of our (awesome) geek community:

- The first one is https://crontab.guru/ . If nothing else, it puts the cronjobs syntax in very simple, visual, straight words. They also offer a payed service in case you want to monitor your jobs.
- In the same spirit of online monitoring (maybe of your interest, I live it here for the records and because it's free), you may find interesting https://cron-job.org/ .

Whatever the resources we use to figure out the crontab line we need, "every 15 minutes" is: `*/15 * * * *` .
To set that up, we open our (user's) cronjob table (*crontab*) and set our job accordingly:

1. Open crontab jobs:

```bash
$ crontab -e
```

2. Set the (celery) job (inside crontab):

```
*/15 * * * * /home/myapp/start_celery.sh
```

This should work, but I didn't test the whole thing. Let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a corn job running your script at startup as long as you don't experience any function crashes.

Start by opening a terminal window and run the command below. Don't forget to `<add your ssh key>` and `<username>`. This will generate the script.sh file for you and save it in $HOME

```
echo -e "ssh -p19199 -i <my ssh key file name> <my username>@server.net\n\nsource /home/myapp/virtualenv/app/3.8/bin/activate\n\ncd /home/myapp/app\n\ncelery -A app.mycelery worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=INFO -f celery.log --detach" >> $HOME/startup.sh
```

Make it executable using the following command:

```
sudo chmod +x $HOME/startup.sh
```

Now create the cron job to run the script when you restart your server. In the terminal create a new cron job.

```
crontab -e
```

This will open a new editor screen for you to write the cron job. Press the letter i on your keyboard to start the insert mode and type the following

```
@reboot sh $HOME/startup.sh
```

Exit the editor and save your changes by pressing **esc** key then type `:wq` and hit **Enter**

Restart your server and the cron job should run the script for you.

Comment: I need to run given code in corn job.

Comment: Copy the code and paste it into `startup.sh` file, it will run in sh as an executable every time you restart your server. I will add this step to my answer.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the steps with the code to copy and run, let me know if I've missed anything or if a step is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage the tasks that should run when a system reboots, shutdowns are alike, you should not make use of cron. These tasks are managed by the Power Management Utilities (pm-utils). Have a look at `man pm-action` and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58405459/8344060) for a somewhat detailed explanation.

Obviously, as a user it is not always possible to configure these hooks for `pm-util` and alternative options are considered. Having a cron-job running every x minutes is an obvious solution that would allow the user to automatically start a job.

The command you would run in cron would look something like:

```
pgrep -f celery 2>/dev/null || /path/to/celery_startup
```

Where  `/path/to/celery_startup` is a simple bash script that contains the commands to be executed (the ones mentioned in the OP).